# How to highlight child item in Expendale list view contains multiple levels?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am having an expendable list view which contains three levels.First I had single level and by following this link http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-highlighting-selected-item-in.html I successfully highlighted the child item. But now I am having 3 level,by following the above link it highlights the wrong child item additionally it have to stay highlighted on onResume(). Can anybody help me to solve this. Any idea will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found answer by myself. I stored the child position in shared pref and once again use the code from above link on setOnGroupExpandListener and return true in hasStableIds() on your BaseExpandableListAdapter.